# Adding a header on the top left hand side of a Tableform matrix

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

The codes I have is:

```
Somebrightsourcesinthesky = 
Labeled[TableForm[{{710, 1, "Very Weak"}, {2000, 1.5, ""}, {5000, 7, 
"Extended"}, {2105 - 2016, 264 - 2640, "Variable"}}, 
TableHeadings -> {{"Moon", "Cassiopedia A", "Cygnus X", 
"Sun"}, {"Flux density Jy", "Expected Ta K" , "Comments"}}], 
"Continuum Sources", Top]
```

I would like to add a heading on the top left hand side. Would anyone be able to assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
table = Labeled[TableForm[{{710, 1, "Very Weak"}, {2000, 1.5, ""}, 
    {5000, 7, "Extended"}, {2105 - 2016, 264 - 2640, "Variable"}}, 
   TableHeadings -> {{"Moon", "Cassiopedia A", "Cygnus X", "Sun"}, 
    {"Flux density Jy", "Expected Ta K", "Comments"}}], "Continuum Sources", Top]

Labeled[table, "HEADER", {{Top, Left}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Panel[table, "HEADER", Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]